# JBEHAVE-JXL : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 39181

Tags: excel-2007, jxl, jbehave, indexoutofboundsexception

JXL VERSION = 2.6.12

JBEHAVE VERSION: 3.6.8

EXCEL :MS EXCEL 2007

I am reading excel  in my Jbehave step class from class path as below and getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The same code is working in standalone java code

> Workbook workbook = null; InputStream stream
>   =this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.xls"); workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(stream); Sheet sheet =
>   workbook.getSheet(0); Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(0,0);

However If I use File System path to read excel in Jbehave Project, I am able to load and read  the content from the sheet in excel

> workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("test.xls "));

Below is the stack trace:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 39181
>           at jxl.read.biff.Record.(Record.java:79)
>           at jxl.read.biff.File.next(File.java:181)
>           at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.parse(WorkbookParser.java:569)
>           at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:271)
>           at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:253)
>           at org.teststepgiven.steps.Test.test(Test.java:33)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParameterisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:537)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner$FineSoFar.run(StoryRunner.java:477)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runStepsWhileKeepingState(StoryRunner.java:457)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runScenarioSteps(StoryRunner.java:421)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runCancellable(StoryRunner.java:297)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.run(StoryRunner.java:211)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.run(StoryRunner.java:172)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:229)
>           at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:201)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: I'm getting the same error!